# Perl encodings question

Tags: perl, url

I need to get a string from `<STDIN>`, written in latin and russian mixed encodings, and convert it to some url:

`$search_url = "http://searchengine.com/search?text=" . uri_escape($query);`

But this proccess goes bad and gives out [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) (a mixture of weird letters). What can I do with Perl to solve it?

Comment: Do you know the encoding of each string?  Do you know all of the encoding present in a string?

Comment: Why do you have a string in mixed encodings? How are you getting this string? Complete sample programs and sample input help people help you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can get started, there's a few things you need to know.

1. You'll need to know the encoding of your input. "Latin" and "russian" aren't (character) encodings.
2. If you're dealing with multiple encodings, you'll need to know what is encoded using which encoding. "It's a mix" isn't good enough.
3. You'll need to know the encoding the site expects the query to use. This should be the same encoding as the page that contains the search form.

Then, it's just a matter of decoding the input using the correct encoding, and encoding the query using the correct encoding. That's the easy part. [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode) provides functions `decode` and `encode` to do just that.