# Perl translation from Ukrainian to English

Tags: perl, utf-8, decode, encode

I am translating the encoded characters to a normal string. But its not working

Here is the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;

my $text = "\x{d1}\x{84}\x{d1}\x{96}\x{d0}\x{bd}\x{d1}\x{81}\x{d1}\x{8c}\x{d0}\x{ba}\x{d0}\x{b0}";
my $decode_text = decode("UTF-8", $text);

print $decode_text;
print "\n";
```

I get the output as:

```
фінська
```

The output is not the normal string

I want the output to be:

```
Finnish
```

Can anyone please help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't want a decoding, you want a translation.

Comment: @clamp Translation in the sense , do you have any example ?

Comment: Any answer would be appreciated

Comment: https://rapidapi.com/collection/google-translate-api-alternatives

Comment: @JosefZ,  How does this help for me to get solution for the problem

Comment: The value present in $text variable is not a valid utf8 encoded string for word "Finnish"  if i use valid utf8 encoded string for word "Finnish" which is "\x46\x69\x6e\x6e\x69\x73\x68" above code works.  You can also try. I am assuming you are double encoded the string

Comment: @amitbhosale, you are right. But I want to translate the input to Finnish. Is that possible ?

Comment: Translating a word to another language would be a different qestion.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514255/perl-encodings-question then only possible to decode the string using proper character set

Comment: None of the above is helping for me to fix this issue

Comment: how you got the $text variable value/string what type of encoding you have used?

Comment: @clamp, No, it would be the question asked. As presumptuous as it sounds, the OP obviously means "English" when they say "normal string". However, recommendations for tools and libraries are off-topic, so we can't help.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what you have there.

```
$ perl -M5.010 -MEncode=decode -Mcharnames=:full -e'
   my $utf8 = "\x{d1}\x{84}\x{d1}\x{96}\x{d0}\x{bd}\x{d1}\x{81}\x{d1}\x{8c}\x{d0}\x{ba}\x{d0}\x{b0}";
   my $ucp = decode("UTF-8", $utf8);
   say sprintf "U+%06X %s", $_, charnames::viacode($_) for unpack("W*", $ucp);
'
U+000444 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EF
U+000456 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I
U+00043D CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EN
U+000441 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES
U+00044C CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER SOFT SIGN
U+00043A CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER KA
U+000430 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A
```

This is `фінська`, so you're getting the expected output.

That said, `фінська` appears to be Ukrainian for `Finnish`.

[image: Google Translation of фінська]

`decode 'UTF-8'` converts from UTF-8 to Unicode Code Points. It doesn't perform natural language translations. For that, you will need some tool, library, API, etc that performs that task, and recommendations for such things are not allowed. But at least you know what you need now.